# Unable to sum up column values and display in end of row in excel using alasql

Tags: javascript, sql, excel, alasql

I have json array value that has to be displayed in various sheets in excel,so I have use the json format as below

```
var opts=[
{
"sheetid": "Ali",
"header": false
},
{
"sheetid": "Ari",
"header": false
}]

var exportArray=[
  [
{
  "driver": "Ari",
  "round_trip_number": "7",
  "trip_name": "L-R-L",
  "vehicle": "WB7520Q",
  "distance_profile": "KM_Scheme1_30_90",
  "scheme_name": "CA_Scheme_A",
  "actual_weight": 0,
  "actual_litre": 0,
  "weight_price": 0,
  "distance_price": 0,
  "trip_price": 0,
  "estimated_distance": 48.44
},
{
  "driver": "Ari",
  "round_trip_number": "6",
  "trip_name": "R-P",
  "vehicle": "WB7520Q",
  "distance_profile": "KM_Scheme1_30_90",
  "scheme_name": "CA_Scheme_A",
  "actual_weight": 8000,
  "actual_litre": 7000,
  "weight_price": 36,
  "distance_price": 60,
  "trip_price": 0,
  "estimated_distance": 656.62
  }
 ],
[
{
  "driver": "Ali",
  "round_trip_number": "4",
  "trip_name": "L-P-L",
  "vehicle": "BGV1852",
  "scheme_name": "TA_Scheme_A",
  "actual_weight": 30000,
  "actual_litre": 21000,
  "weight_price": 0,
  "distance_price": 0,
  "trip_price": 0,
  "drum_qty": 140,
  "drum_price": 0,
  "estimated_distance": 313.5
}
 ]]
```

I need to sum the column values in excel and display in the end of the respective column.I using alasql script to do this functionality.
The excel is generated while I use below query .

```
 var result = alasql('SELECT * INTO XLSX("DriverComponesation.xlsx",?) FROM ?', [opts, exportArray]);
```

But When I use the below query to sum up column values the excel is not generated.

```
var result = alasql('select * INTO XLSX("DriverComponesation.xlsx",?) from (SELECT * FROM ? x union all select null, null ,null ,null ,null ,null ,sum(actual_weight) actual_weight,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null from ? ) o ', [opts, exportArray]);
```

can anyone help me get the sum of coulmns in excel using above json array.